# Standard Library version of "Wait for Alert/Event" for threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, events, c++11, c++14

Does C++ have any notion of thread synchronization by Wait+Wake of some kind? Waiting on an event, alert, object, etc? Something like `WaitForSingleObject`, WaitOnAddress, etc? The only things I can find are `std::thread::join`, and fence/sync stuff like locks and `std::atomic`. Is there more to C++'s threading yet? Is there more coming in the future?

Comment: FYI: [N4195 `std::synchronic<T>`](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4195.pdf) was proposed for C++1y. It's like a futex syscall/WaitOnAddress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need signaling between threads C++11 has [Condition Variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). Condition variables will lock threads that need access to this variable until they are "signaled" by the thread that initially locked a resource. You can build up higher level constructs like WaitFor assuming you're okay with thread level locking.

If you're wanting something like C# Tasks, not as of C++11 in the Standard Library. In C++11 only threading primitives were added to the language, their semantics are at the "thread level". Trying to implement them without some language features being added is messy at best.

My next suggestion if condition variables don't satisfy is to invert program control using callbacks. Realtime processing libraries like OpenMAX and OpenSL ES don't use "events" they use callbacks on the same thread. These callbacks are where you hook in your code to send more data to a device or to quickly store data somewhere else for processing later.

Lastly see if you can change your problem to make it fit an existing library. Libraries like https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/ are pretty much the gold standard for C++ threading. If a good solution for a common problem exists there's a good chance they'll have one.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there had to be at least one major feature of C++11's threading that I wasn't finding, and it was std::condition_variable. Now, I just need to benchmark it to see if I can divorce myself from OS-specific synchronization concepts for good ;)

Answer (score 1):

> ***Is there more to C++'s threading yet?***

**Yes. These are not deep dark secrets - all quite public and easily accessible information.**

See [***cppreference.com -Thread support library***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

For some in depth, more scholarly discussion, start here: The C++ Programming Language - Fourth Edition- Bjarne Stroustrup:

> **42. Threads and Tasks**
>
> 42.1. Introduction
>
> The C++ standard support for concurrency is introduced in a tutorial
> manner in §5.3. This chapter and the previous one provide a more
> detailed and systematic view. We call an activity potentially executed
> concurrently with other activities a task. A thread is the
> system-level representation of a computer’s facilities for executing a
> task....
>
> 42.2. **Threads**
>
> A thread is an abstraction of the computer hardware’s notion of a
> computation. The C++ standard-library threads are intended to map
> one-to-one with the operating system’s threads. We use threads when
> several tasks in a program need to progress concurrently. On a system
> with several processing units (“cores”), threads allows us to use
> those units...
>
> 42.3. **Avoiding Data Races**
>
> ...These simple rules are based on the idea of avoiding attempts to
> simultaneously access data, so they don’t require locking and lead to
> maximally efficient programs. Where they cannot be used, for example,
> because lots of data needs to be shared, use some form of locking: •
> **Mutexes:** A mutex (a mutual exclusion variable) is an object used to
> represent the exclusive right to access some resource. To access the
> resource, acquire the mutex, access, and then release the mutex
> (§5.3.4, §42.3.1). • **Condition variables:** A condition variable is a
> variable used by a thread to wait for an event generated by another
> thread or a timer (§5.3.4.1, §42.3.4)...
>
> 42.3.1. **Mutexes**
>
> A mutex is an object used to represent exclusive access to some
> resource. Thus, it can be used to protect against data races and to
> synchronize access to data shared between multiple threads. The
> “plain” mutex is the simplest, smallest, and fastest mutex.
>
> 42.4. **Task-Based Concurrency**
>
> So far, this chapter focused on the mechanisms for running concurrent
> tasks: the focus was on threads, avoiding race conditions, and
> synchronizing threads. For many concurrent tasks, I find this focus on
> mechanisms distracting from the real task (sic!) of specifying
> concurrent tasks. This section focuses on specifying a simple kind of
> task: a task that does one thing given arguments and produces one
> result.
>
> 42.4.1. **future and promise**
>
> As mentioned in §5.3.5, communication between tasks is handled by a
> **future/promise pair**. **A task puts its result into a promise, and a task that needs the result retrieves the result from the
> corresponding future:**
>
> 42.4.6. **async()**
>
> The async() function is basically a simple interface to a launcher of
> unknown sophistication. A call of async() returns a future where R
> is the type of its task’s result. For example...

**And continue.....**

@MorphingDragon's answer about Condition Variables is certainly important, but there is far more to it than that. Although Intel's TBB is certainly excellent, the STL for C++11 now includes the above listed features for supporting concurrency, many previously available only through supplementary libraries.

Comment: Thanks, but I am highly familiar with all of these concepts. I've been doing windows threading (and occasional other OS's) for 10 years. I asked what the Standard Library has to offer. The standard library had almost nothing in this area until C++11 so I am trying to catch up to the latest actually-available stuff cross-platform stuff offered in the standard library. I accepted the other answer not because it mentioned the concept of a condition variable, but because it mentioned std::condition_variable was a live, working thing.

Comment: See edit regarding Task-Based Concurrency and `future/promise` - an important new way of handling inter-thread communication. It is all there in C++11.

Comment: @Vector if we went over all the details in C++11 concurrency we would be here for a while. :)

Comment: @MorphingDragon - no argument. That's why I said "And continue..."